# Writing sequential files with different kinds of lines or records

Tags: file-io, cobol

Let's assume that I want to write the following to a sequential output txt file.

```
!---!  
This is a report!  
!---!  
Here is the list of records:   
001 Jack  
002 Alice  
!---!  
Number of crimes:   
Jack: 01  
Alice: 02
```

The thing is that, when I define a sequential output file and its contents, I do not know how I should define all these different types of lines. for instance `!---!` has to be like a constant value while `001 Jack` should be written like:

```
FD OUTPUT-FILE.  
    01 PERSON-RECORD.
        05 ID PIC 999.
        05 NAME PIC X(10).
```

on the other hand, after `"Number of crimes:"` there should be the record:

```
01 CRIMES.
    05 NAME PIC X.
    05 NO-OF-CRIME PIC 99.
```

but if I write `01 PERSON-RECORD.` and `01 CRIMES.` under the same `FD`, then I encounter problems when trying to write to output file. The values of `CRIMES` actually goes to the value of `PERSON-RECORD`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Knowing which compiler helps in identifying a solution.

Comment: @RickSmith I am using opencobolide for linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Any ideas?

In `FILE-CONTROL` use `ORGANIZATION LINE SEQUENTIAL`.

In the `DATA DIVISION.` use,

```
FILE SECTION.
FD OUTPUT-FILE.
01 OUTPUT-RECORD PIC X(80).

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 CONSTANT-TEXT-1 PIC X(5) VALUE "!---!".
01 CONSTANT-TEXT-2 PIC X(17) VALUE "This is a report!"
01 CONSTANT-TEXT-3 PIC X(28) VALUE "Here is the list of records:"
01 CONSTANT-TEXT-4 PIC X(17) VALUE "Number of crimes:".
01 PERSON-RECORD.
    05 ID PIC 999.
    05 NAME PIC X(10).
01 CRIMES.
    05 NAME PIC X.
    05 NO-OF-CRIME PIC 99.
```

In the `PROCEDURE DIVISION`, for the `WRITE` statements use,

```
WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD FROM CONSTANT-TEXT-1
WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD FROM CONSTANT-TEXT-2
WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD FROM CONSTANT-TEXT-3
WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD FROM CONSTANT-TEXT-4
WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD FROM PERSON-RECORD
WRITE OUTPUT-RECORD FROM CRIMES
```

in whatever sequence you need to produce the report.

You need not use `CONSTANT-TEXT`, use any name that has meaning for the program.

Comment: That seems intuitive. However, I was wondering, in `01 OUTPUT-RECORD PIC X(80).` does 80 suggest that each line is maximum of 80 chars? Thanks

Comment: @Huzo -Yes, but it can be any length you need. The 80 appears to be a common number due to past uses, such as, 80-column punched cards, 80-column screens, 80-column printers (for early PCs), etc.